# Banach space operator norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

$X,Y$ are Banach spaces. $A,B\in L(X,Y)$ and there are $A^{-1},B^{-1}\in L(X,Y)$. Prove that if 
$$\|B-A\|\leqslant \frac1{2\| A^{-1}\|}$$
then
$$\|B^{-1}-A^{-1}\| \leqslant 2\| A^{-1}\|^2 \|B-A\|$$

I could use some hints on proving this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

Let $H=B-A$.

Here's the hint:

$(A+H)^{-1}-A^{-1} = A^{-1}((I+H A^{-1})^{-1}-I) = A^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (H A^{-1} )^k$.

And some details:

> We have $\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty (H A^{-1} )^k \| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \|H A^{-1} \|^k = \|H A^{-1} \| {1 \over 1- \|H A^{-1} \|} \le 2 \|H A^{-1} \|$. This gives $\|(A+H)^{-1}-A^{-1}\| \le 2 \| A^{-1}\|^2 \|H\|$, as required.